# Testing if no radio buttons are checked

Tags: jquery

I would like to check to see if a box is checked using jquery.
My aim is to prevent the form from hiding if no option is selected.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){  
var opt = $('input[name=value]:checked').attr('value');
if(opt!='undefined'){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: 'option='+opt,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{   
 alert(opt);

}
     });
}       
return false;
});
```

html

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="radio" name="value" value="1" />1<br>
<input type="radio" name="value" value="2" />2<br>
<input type="radio" name="value" value="3" />3<br>
<input type="radio" name="value" value="4" />3<br>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Guys, selector `$('input[name=value]:checked')` IS working. It's not the mistake here; it's about `'undefined'`. Still would prefer to rewrite this checking `.length` first. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest just checking `$('input[name=value]:checked').length` before doing anything else. ) If no element was checked, it will be equal to 0. In other words, replace

```
var opt = $('input[name=value]:checked').attr('value');
```

...with

```
var $checkedElement = $('input[name=value]:checked');
if (! $checkedElement.length) {
   // no option was selected, return false or alert
} 
var opt = $checkedElement.val();
```

Your original code, though, is pretty close, with just a single mistake: you should compare `opt` to `undefined` (a *variable*), not to `'undefined'` (a string).

```
if (opt != undefined) { ... do the thing .. }
```

The `opt != 'undefined'` will actually always evaluate to `false`, as no radio button in your HTML has value `'undefined'`. Again, consider the difference between `false` and `'false'` - the latter is actually a truthy value (though not equal to `true`);

Answer (score 1):

```
$("checkbox").is(":checked");
```

This return true or false. if is checked or not

Answer (score 0):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ZKC2z/

good read: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

also there is a `:not` selector

`.is(":checked")` will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

if not checked using `.is()`

```
if ( ! $("input").is(':checked') )
```

Just adding `!` before, or using `.not()`

```
if ( ! $("input").not(':checked') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps...

```
$("#submit").click(function(){  
var opt = $('input[name=value]:checked').attr('value');
if(opt){
 alert(opt + "- ok, posting!");
 return true;
} else {
 alert('pick something first');
 return false;
}
});
```